# Breadcrumb implementation

Tags: asp.net

I am confused about the following scenario :

TYpical category, products display.
Categories will be dynamic, so will products.
So, to show all products under a category, I need to show a breadcrumb, and a left menu showing list of categories.
Now, do we need to use SiteMap feature of asp.net, or not.
SiteMap feature is for static page hierarchy or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create dynamic sitemap.check out the following link

[Creating Dynamic ASP.NET SiteMap using LINQ](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=281)

Answer (score 1):

You  make your **[custom sitemapProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479320.aspx)** and let it deliver an object that implements the **[IHierarchicalDataSource Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchicaldatasource.aspx)** that deliver your products & cateory objects.

finally the only thing you have to do is bind a **[SitmapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.aspx)** against this DataSource.